# известная ошибка 150 SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Хочу создать таблицу, которую случайно удалил, когда удалял внешние ключи(всякое бывает:( ). И теперь когда создаю ее заного, мне пишет что внешний ключ с неправильным типом данных. **(ошибка: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")** Внешних ключей ссылающихся на создаваему таблицу нет.

#1005 - Невозможно создать таблицу `aviato_db`.`products` (ошибка: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
create table `products`(`id` int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key, `name` text not null,
`description` text not null, `category` int not null, `tags` int not null)
```

Comment: Значит есть ключи. Ищите

Comment: их нет, в phpmyadmin если смотреть какие есть внешние ключи, их нет, через консоль та же история

Comment: Вспоминается "ДМБ", `- "Ты суслика видишь?"`, `- "Нет"`, `- "А он есть!!!"`

Comment: так не смешно, я уже часа 2 сижу не понимаю в чем трабла(

Comment: Да я и не смеюсь. Система где-то видит этот ключ. Как правило сообщение об ошибке более информативно, не могли-бы вы его полностью в вопрос добавить

Comment: могу, #1005 - Невозможно создать таблицу `aviato_db`.`products` (ошибка: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: В других таблицах ключи ссылающиеся на таблицу `products` поищите. Они там реально должны быть. Ну не бывает чудес.

Comment: нету таблиц ссылающихся на products

Comment: Единственное что еще может быть, что ключ находится в таблице из другой схемы на сервере

Comment: как мне его увидить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111842/discussion-between-namerek-and-istinnavvine).

Comment: Я не могу писать в чате, у меня нету аккаунта(

Comment: с 50 репутации.

Comment: А куда вы дели старую уч. запись? Полчаса назад она ещё была.

Comment: это была учетка, которая снизу создается, там ник и емаил

Comment: Так в чём проблема? Выйдите из текущей записи, и зайдите с той, с которой задали вопрос.

Comment: это не аккаунт был

Comment: Извините, а что тогда? 4 месяца зарегестрирован и 93 репутаци, час назад вы задали с него вопрос.

Comment: Или это были не вы, а вы взяли ник пользователя, который задал этото вопрос?